# how to make text automatically stack when resizing the browser window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is that when I am resizing the browser window, the first text breaks up. It should never break up the words, just show the entire sentence no matter how small the window gets. I've tried with queries, but can't figure out how to do it correctly. See the image to understand the issue.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <h2>
                <li class="list-inline-item">LYD</li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">&#9702;</li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">LYS</li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">&#9702;</li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">LED</li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">&#9702;</li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">AV</li>
            </h2>
        </ul>
    </div>
          
    <br>
    
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="middle">
            <h2>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> 57 67 18 14
            </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
          
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul li { display: inline; }

ul.list-inline{
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.middle{
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

[image: How it's behaving right now]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working? See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is unclear which behavior you are hoping to have. Should the text overflow the window with/without horizontal scrollbar, should the font size decrease ?

Comment: See the image under the css code

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that the content, namely the list and list items all inherit their width from the containing col-7.
If you know the exact width of the text you can just put an exact width property on it-

```
ul {
    width: 302px;
}
```

In a more dynamic way, though, you can use either `white-space` or `max-content`

```
/* white-space */ 
ul {
    white-space: nowrap
}

/* max-content*/
ul.list-inline {
    width: intrinsic;           /* Safari/WebKit uses a non-standard name */
    width: -moz-max-content;    /* Firefox/Gecko */
    width: -webkit-max-content; /* Chrome */
}
```